# Warning API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'

Tags: android

When I ran my gradle scripts I got the following error.

I updated the play services version in my project by changing
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'` to 
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` but still, Studio is giving me a warning message.

project level build.gradle

[image]

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2` just use this one.

Comment: I tried but warning is still there